# Is there any benefit to installing Heroku addon for MongoHQ/Compose?

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongohq, compose-db

I use Heroku to host my node.js api. I use MongoHQ (now Compose) for my database. I had gone directly to MongoHQ and setup an account quite sometime ago and I've just setup my mongoose connection directly to my MongoHQ/Compose account.

Is there any benefit to doing this via the heroku addon? I guess what I am wondering is since I am sure they are all hosted on AWS if I do it via the addon does it perhaps communicate within an AWS local network?

Really just wondering if there are any benefits to doing it via the addon vs. manually.

Thanks!